# Hide system bar icons , back, home and recent apps

Tags: android, statusbar, homescreen

I want to hide icons available on the system bar (back, home and recent apps) in android 4.2.2.

Can someone please tell me how it can be achieved.

Note: want to hide only icons not the entire system bar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE); // This will make the nav buttons into little dots
}
```